# Sorting Algorithm Not Passing

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, pointers

I'm trying to take a file and run it through a sorting algorithm, insertion sort in this case. After I pass it through the algorithm and print the array, it doesn't look sorted. My thinking is because I'm trying to pass an array to the function, and view the information through a pointer, but I think I'm messing it up.

```
void insertionSort(int arr[]) {
    int key, j;
    for(int i = 1; i < (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)); i++) {
        int key = arr[i];
        int j = i-1;
        while(j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) {
            arr[j+1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arr[j+1] = key;
    }
}
```

I have the function set to void because I thought I'd be able to just access the array since it is a pointer. Would it be better if I returned the array? My logic is obviously wrong, so any pointers (no pun intended) would be great.

Here is the block of code from my `main()`

```
case 2:
    printf("Filling array...\n");

    fp = fopen("Random.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("\nError opening Random.txt\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)); i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    insertionSort(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)); i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Hint 1: `void insertionSort(int arr[]) {` is exactly the same as `void insertionSort(int *arr) {` (yes it's a pointer even when you write []). Hint 2: what's `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)`?

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` in the `insertionSort` routine will be `sizeof(int*)` which is 8 byte, so what you are actually doing is `8 / 4` , which is 2

Comment: @immibis I'm using `sizeof` to iterate through the entire array. I'm under the impression that I can't use `.length()` for example because C is not OOP?

@0.sh Read above comment. Using `sizeof` to iterate through array. If there's a better method, I'm open to it.

Comment: `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int) = 2` on x86_64 and `1` on x86.

Comment: @InfoSecNick except `arr` (in the function) isn't an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void insertionSort(int arr[]) {
```

Arrays decay to pointers when passed to functions, so this is basically

```
void insertionSort(int *arr) {
```

which means this will not give you the number of elements in the array

```
for(int i = 1; i < (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)); i++) {
```

You need to explicitly pass the size of the array to the function.

```
void insertionSort(int arr[], int size) {
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        int key = arr[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

To call the function:

```
insertionSort(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int));
```

In `main()`, where the array is created, you can use `sizeof(A) / sizeof(int)`, because `main()` knows the size of the array.

Comment: In other words, `sizeof (array)` only reports the size of the array *in the scope in which `array` is declared*. Otherwise, it's just `sizeof (a pointer)`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that an array decays to a pointer. Is there any reason to this? Or is this just C? Thanks again.